# Is it possible to get JDBC Connection object from SQLException object?

Tags: java, jdbc, jersey, jax-rs

This is what I want to do: I'm writing a Restful application using JAX-RS. I have written a exception mapper to map `SQLException` to HTTP status code 500.

```
@Provider
public class SQLExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SQLException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(SQLException exception) {
        Logger.error(exception);
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

I have lots of these situations in code:

```
try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    /* do some stuff */
    conn.commit();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    conn.rollback();
    /* re-throw SQLException again so exception mapper converts it to HTTP status 500 */
    throw ex;
} finally {
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    conn.close();
}
```

Actually I don't like `conn.rollback(); throw ex;`. What I really want is to get JDBC `Connection` object from `SQLException` object so I can rollback connection inside exception mapper. Is this possible? Another question that is not related to this question is: I do some extensive math processing between database calls. I close connection after I finish each phase and open it at the beginning of next phase. So inside one request I do multiple open/close. Is this bad pattern?

Comment: Constantly opening and closing (physical) connections is not such a good idea. It is a quite costly operation and you would be better off using a connection pool instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using connection pool. Application is running inside glassfish. I was afraid there is a significant overhead even if I use connection pool.

Comment: If you're using a connection pool there is no 'significant overhead'. That's the point of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get JDBC Connection object from SQLException object?

No.

Answer (score 1):

I think it isn't possible. The [SQL-Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) has no property which stores the connection

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a declarative transaction management such as in Spring framework.  This will relief you of a lot of boiler-plate code and will leave your data access tier quite clean, as well as the business logic.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s05.html

The idea would be to have a transactional service tier on top of your data access tier; the service tier would candidly call your daos, and declare itself `@Transactional`; you would have no code at all to manage exceptions in either of both tiers (you delegate the commits and rollbacks to the framework)